# reading .csv into EBImage

Tags: r, csv, image-processing

I'm rather new to R and image processing. I have a series of images stored as csv files that I would like to read into EBImage. I have been using ImageJ in the past. I've been using the imageData(y) command but keep getting the error that my "object must be an array" when I try to read in the file.

I think the issue I'm having is that I've imported the csv as a spatial indexed matrix (x,y) and I need to convert to an array (x,y,value).

```
    test=read.csv('Fe_Kα1.csv', sep=",", header=FALSE)
    test1 <- as.matrix(test) 
    writeImage('test1')
Error in validImage(x) : object must be an array
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide the code to look at, and sample of the images represented as CSVs

Comment: Thank you. I think the issue I'm having is that I've imported the csv as a matrix (x,y) and I need to convert to an array (x,y,value).

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue here, as `writeImage` does support plain (x, y) matrices. For example, the following works: `EBImage::writeImage(matrix(0, 3, 3), "img.png")`. Could you please share a reproducible example of your code that fails?